# SonarCloud New Code and Code Coverage Setup for Spring Boot

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jhipster, sonarcloud

I am trying to perform analysis on the new code however the sonarCloud seems to analyze everything. I am not sure what's missing.

I am using 2 Github workflows, one during pull request

```
name: Application CI
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - development
      - staging
      - main
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
jobs:
  validation:
    name: 'Gradle Wrapper Validation'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@v1
  pipeline:
    name: something Pipeline
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 40
    env:
      NODE_VERSION: 16.14.0
      SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED: DETECT
      SPRING_JPA_SHOW_SQL: false
      JHI_DISABLE_WEBPACK_LOGS: true
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.14.0
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: 11
      - name: Cache SonarCloud packages
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.sonar/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
      - name: Cache Gradle packages
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/caches
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle
      - name: Build and analyze
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
        run: ./gradlew test jacocoTestReport sonarqube --info -x integrationTest
```

while the other one during merge

```
name: Application CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development
      - staging
      - main
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '11'
      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew -Pprod -Pwar clean bootWar
      - name: Upload WAR
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: artifact
          path: build/libs/something-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
      - name: Download WAR
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: artifact
      #Deploy the artifact (JAR) into AWS Beanstalk
      - name: Deploy to EB
        uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v20
        with:
          aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          #aws_session_token: ${{ secrets.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN }}
          use_existing_version_if_available: true
          application_name: something-stg
          environment_name: staging
          version_label: ${{github.SHA}}
          region: ap-southeast-1
          deployment_package: something-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
          wait_for_environment_recovery: 600
```

buid.gradle

```
...
apply from: "gradle/sonar.gradle"
...
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "somethingapp_something"
        property "sonar.organization", "somethingapp"
        property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonarcloud.io"
    }
}
```

sonar.gradle

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    executionData tasks.withType(Test)
    classDirectories.from = files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs)
    sourceDirectories.from = files(sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs)

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}

plugins.withType(JacocoPlugin) {
    tasks["test"].finalizedBy 'jacocoTestReport'
}


file("sonar-project.properties").withReader {
    Properties sonarProperties = new Properties()
    sonarProperties.load(it)

    sonarProperties.each { key, value ->
        sonarqube {
            properties {
                property key, value
            }
        }
    }
}

test.dependsOn webapp_test
compileJava.dependsOn processResources
processResources.dependsOn bootBuildInfo
```

Any idea why my simple PR keeps on giving me the same analysis information?

[image]

PR listed in SonarCloud

[image]

Comment: Is the PR analysed in sonar cloud? So do you see it under the PR list/view in sonar cloud? https://docs.sonarcloud.io/improving/pull-request-analysis/

Comment: Yes it appears under the PR list with similar stats as shown in Github. Updated the question with appropriate screenshot.